# I don't feel that my current role is a great fit. How should I bring up my desire to change in an industry that is currently in a downturn?

Tags: job-search, work-environment, career-development, new-job, job-change

I'm currently a mechanical engineer in one of the very large oil & gas companies. Because of the price of oil, there have been massive layoffs recently. I survived the latest round of layoffs which involved every engineering group in the company.

I've been with the company for a few years and have been feeling like the engineering role I'm in is not a great fit for many reasons that have to do with job content and team culture. This is not my first job in the oil industry and I feel like by now I have a pretty good inner compass in order to be able to determine a more suitable role for me. I would like to look within the same company for a new role, however, since the mass layoffs, I feel like there is no ability for me to move. I've talked to our Ombuds office to get strategies for dealing with my current role, but I feel like they have not worked due to cultural issues. Should I reach out to someone else within the company? Or, should I just look for work in another industry? I missed my chance to move back to my previous company in 2014 before the downturn and now I'm regretting it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a word with a manager or HR and tell them that you want a new challenge, you really like the firm, feel a valued member of the team having been kept on despite layoffs but after a few years you want some new opportunities/ chances to learn & grow - it's always better to frame these things positively rather than "I hate my team I want a new one".

If you are considering looking for work in another industry then there is no downside to being a little more direct with your current firm if the first approach doesn't work- you can play hardball with them knowing you would be happy enough to leave anyway.  If nothing has happened within a few weeks of the first chat, then have another meeting and let them know you'll have to look around elsewhere if they can't improve your conditions

Comment: I agree, if you're unhappy enough to be contemplating a total move then you can afford to push your luck.